# How to delete jobs from MGMT_JOB in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-enterprise-manager

I created two jobs through Enterprise Manager. Now I want to delete these jobs. I am trying delete jobs with this query but getting error

```
set linesize 300;
column job_name format a50;
column job_owner format a30;

select job_id, job_name, job_owner from mgmt_job;

exec mgmt_job_engine.stop_all_executions_with_id('8DDA2C82912B6C9FE050A8C035641D49',TRUE);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

commit;

exec mgmt_job_engine.delete_job('8DDA2C82912B6C9FE050A8C035641D49');

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20414: The specified job has active executions.
ORA-06512: at "SYSMAN.MGMT_JOB_ENGINE", line 4490
ORA-06512: at "SYSMAN.MGMT_JOB_ENGINE", line 5183
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

How to solve this problem
Thanks

Comment: Try this `exec mgmt_job_engine.stop_all_executions_with_id('8DDA2C82912B6C9FE050A8C035641D49')` removed TRUE

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with this query

```
UPDATE mgmt_job_exec_summary SET status = 8, end_time = (sysdate-1) WHERE job_id = '8DDA2C82912B6C9FE050A8C035641D49';

commit;
```

Then again execute this query

```
exec mgmt_job_engine.delete_job('8DDA2C82912B6C9FE050A8C035641D49');

commit;
```